# PHP5 to PHP7 upgrade issues

Tags: php

Recently I've upgraded to PHP7 from PHP5 on CentOS server. I run a forum software on there and due to certain things being deprecated and so forth, some of the code within the forum software returns php parsing issues.

One of the current issues i'm having difficulty understanding, alongside of fixing, is:

```
Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings
```

The block of code causing the error is:

```
if( in_array( trim( $value[0] ), $curr_values ) )
        {
            $this->parsed[] = trim( $value[1] ); //error line
        }
```

I've tried turning parsed into an array by doing

```
this->parsed=array();
```

But it returns a follow-up error such as

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string
```

Anyway, can anyone sort of shed some light on this and as to why this issue is relevant after upgrading?

Comment: `$var[]` is normally used to *append* something to an array. since your error indicates that you have a string instead of an array, why don't you try *appending to the string* the way strings usually are appended? (`.=`)

Comment: This looks like a good document for you to become familiar with http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I will do just that. Sorry, sometimes it takes someone else to shed some light on the simplest things.

Comment: It looks like the code is checking the first character in the string. You can try to convert the string to a character array